Build for sdk 28 in Intellij IDEA
I'm trying to build an android project targeting sdk-28 to go around some restrictions in newer APIs regarding executing some binaries installed by my app.
The issue I have is that once I create the project and set the target sdk and min sdk to 28 I can't compile the project because of some errors regarding some dependencies.
I tried creating the project in Android Studio, downgrade agp and target sdk but I get the same errors when opening in Intellij IDEA. How can I fix them?
40 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:

  1.  Dependency 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.1' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 33, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

  2.  Dependency 'androidx.compose.material:material-ripple-android:1.5.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 33, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

  3.  Dependency 'androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core-android:1.5.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 33, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

  4.  Dependency 'androidx.compose.material:material-android:1.5.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 33, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

  5.  Dependency 'androidx.compose.animation:animation-core-android:1.5.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 33, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

  6.  Dependency 'androidx.compose.animation:animation-android:1.5.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 33, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

  7.  Dependency 'androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-layout-android:1.5.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 33, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

  8.  Dependency 'androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-android:1.5.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 33, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

  9.  Dependency 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-data-android:1.5.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 33, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

 10.  Dependency 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-unit-android:1.5.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 33, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

 11.  Dependency 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-geometry-android:1.5.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 33, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

 12.  Dependency 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-util-android:1.5.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 33, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

 13.  Dependency 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-text-android:1.5.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 33, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

 14.  Dependency 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview-android:1.5.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 33, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

 15.  Dependency 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-android:1.5.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 33, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

 16.  Dependency 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics-android:1.5.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 33, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

 17.  Dependency 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-android:1.5.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 33, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

 18.  Dependency 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:1.5.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 33, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

 19.  Dependency 'androidx.activity:activity:1.9.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 34, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

 20.  Dependency 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.9.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 34, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

 21.  Dependency 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.9.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 34, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

 22.  Dependency 'androidx.emoji2:emoji2:1.4.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 34, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

 23.  Dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.7.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 34, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

 24.  Dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.7.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 34, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

 25.  Dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.7.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 34, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

 26.  Dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.7.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 34, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

 27.  Dependency 'androidx.savedstate:savedstate-ktx:1.2.1' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 33, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

 28.  Dependency 'androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.2.1' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 33, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

 29.  Dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.7.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 34, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

 30.  Dependency 'androidx.customview:customview-poolingcontainer:1.0.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 32 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 32, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

 31.  Dependency 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 34, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

 32.  Dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.13.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 34, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

 33.  Dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.7.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 34, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

 34.  Dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 34, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

 35.  Dependency 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-saveable-android:1.5.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 33, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

 36.  Dependency 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-android:1.5.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 33, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

 37.  Dependency 'androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.4.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 34, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

 38.  Dependency 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.2.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 33, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

 39.  Dependency 'androidx.profileinstaller:profileinstaller:1.3.1' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 33, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).

 40.  Dependency 'androidx.startup:startup-runtime:1.1.1' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 31 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-28.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 31, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).


You are using a newer version of dependencies which require a new Compile SDK because they are using the latest APIs from it so if you want to downgrade to SDK v28 you have to downgrade the dependencies you are using too.

Setting a version for material 3 in gradle did nothing. it still uses 1.1.1

@AlexandruNitan I think for androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.1 there is no way to downgrade because the previous version will be 1.0.0 and it is the first stable version so if you want to use compose you have to build your app against targetSDK 33

right, i feel stupid xD
The compile sdk isn't the same as the target sdk. So to build the app for android 28 with compose I need to compile for 34
